# Check for a condition periodically without blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, do-while

In my project, function `clipsUpdate` reads some facts which are set by CLIPS without the interference of my C++ code. Based on the read facts, clipsUpdate calls the needed function.

```
void updateClips(void)
{
     // read clipsAction

     switch(clipsAction)
     {
         case ActMove:
                 goToPosition (0, 0, clipsActionArg);
                 break;
     }
}
```

In `goToPosition` function, a message is sent to the vehicle to move to the specified position and then a while loop is used to wait until the vehicle reaches the position.

```
void goToPosition(float north, float east, float down)
{
     // Prepare and send the message

     do 
     {
          // Read new location information.
     }while(/*Specified position reached?*/)
}
```

The problem is that `updateClips` should be called every 500 ms and when the `goToPosition` function is called, the execution is blocked until the target location is reached. During this waiting period, something may happen that requires the vehicle to stop. Therefore, updateClips should be called every 500 ms no matter what, and it should be able to stop executing `goToPosition` if it's running.

I tried using threads as following, but it didn't work successfully with me and it was difficult for me to debug. I think it can be done with a simpler and cleaner way.

```
case ActMove:
      std::thread t1(goToPosition, 0, 0, clipsActionArg);
      t1.detach();
      break;
```

My question is, how can I check if the target location is reached without blocking the execution, i.e., without using `while`?

Comment: You need to either properly implement multithreaded app or make it event driven. Neither one is simple.

Comment: Thanks Slava for the your quick answer. I thought there may be some other simpler way. I'll try to go with one of those. Which one do you suggest? and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want an event-driven model.

In an event-driven model, your main engine is a tight loop that reads events, updates state, then waits for more events.

Some events are time based, others are input based.

The only code that is permitted to block your main thread is the main loop, where it blocks until a timer hits or a new event arrives.

It might very roughly look like this:

```
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
void main_loop( engine_state* state ) {
  bool bContinue = true;
  while(bContinue) {
    update_ui(state);
    while(bContinue && process_message(state, 10ms)) {
      bContinue = update_state(state);
    }
    bContinue = update_state(state);
  }
}
```

`update_ui` provides feedback to the user, if required.

`process_message(state, duration)` looks for a message to process, or for 10ms to occur.  If it sees a message (like `goToPosition`), it modifies *state* to reflect that message (for example, it might store the desired destionation).  It does not block, nor does it take lots of time.

If no message is recived in `duration` time, it returns anyhow without modifying `state` (I'm assuming you want things to happen even if no new input/messages occur).

`update_state` takes the `state` and evolves it.  `state` might have a last updated time stamp; `update_state` would then make the "physics" reflect the time since last one.  Or do any other updates.

The point is that `process_message` doesn't do work on the state (it encodes desires), while `update_state` advances "reality".

It returns `false` if the main loop should exit.

`update_state` is called once for every `process_message` call.

`updateClips` being called every 500ms can be encoded as a repeated automatic event in the queue of messages `process_message` reads.

```
void process_message( engine_state* state, std::chrono::milliseconds ms ) {
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  while (start + ms > std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) {
    // engine_state::delayed is a priority_queue of timestamp/action
    // ordered by timestamp:
    while (!state->delayed.empty()) {
      auto stamp = state->delayed.front().stamp;
      if (stamp >= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) {
        auto f = state->queue.front().action;
        state->queue.pop();
        f(stamp, state);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    //engine_state.queue is std::queue<std::function<void(engine_state*)>>
    if (!state->queue.empty()) {
      auto f = state->queue.front();
      state->queue.pop();
      f(state);
    }
  }
}
```

The repeated polling is implemented as a delayed action that, as its first operation, inserts a new delayed action due 500ms after this one.  We pass in the time the action was due to run.

"Normal" events can be instead pushed into the normal action `queue`, which is a sequence of `std::function<void(engine_state*)>` and executed in order.

If there is nothing to do, the above function busy-waits for `ms` time and then returns.  In some cases, we might want to go to sleep instead.

This is just a sketch of an event loop.  There are many, many on the internet.

Comment: Many many thanks for your answer and for the whole time it took to be written. I'll go through slowly and will look for a good tutorial for event-driven model. Thanks